# Excel VBA multiple column combo box

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I was wondering if it is possible to pull through data from SQL covering multiple columns but displaying only one column in a Combo box?

So to explain:

I have a table in SQL call Portfolio and from an Excel Combo box I need users to select the required portfolio. Ideally I'd like to display just the portfolio name, however I am able to create multiple portfolios with the same name. The thing that makes these portfolios unique is the Portfolio ID.

So what I'm trying to do is pass into SQL the portfolio ID while the user selects the portfolio name from the combo box.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is. You can set the columncount to whatever you need, then simply set the relevant columnwidths to 0 in the properties window to hide the ones you don't want shown.

Comment: Perfect thanks Rory, when I'm now passing the selected variable back into SQL for the query. How do I change the code below to select the first column: sPortfolio = CB_Portfolio.value

Comment: Via the `List` property: `sPortfolio = CB_Portfolio.List(CB_Portfolio.Listindex, 1)`

Comment: Brilliant Thanks so much!